# Why is there no PostBack for a form on a UserControl?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a problem understanding where I am losing the ability to catch the PostBack trigger or simply the handler method of serverclick in this setup and placing breakpoints only shows the PostBack occurs on rendering (Page_Load) but not after submit button is clicked. Allow me to elaborate on the scenario and keep in mind I have limited ability to change the way it is done and must figure out a way to make it work with minor changes using ASP.net / C# / WebForms / Bootstrap 4.5 per the client.

`Dashboard.aspx` [main page] has a simple (top nav showing the logo and logged in user's name with a signout drop down, sidebar menu which upon individual click will load into a display area) and the display area is an `asp:PlaceHolder` element:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="TheScreen">
```

When the [main page] is loaded, it makes an API call and processes a collection of objects received and generates adding a series of UserControl `Control1` objects (this can be zero items or n items) let's call this [default state] of the landing so we can refer to it later.

Each of the `Control1` (which have unique IDs) have 3 buttons to perform 3 different actions.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="action1" runat="server" onserverclick="Command_Click">Do First Action</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="action2" runat="server" onserverclick="Command_Click">Do Second Action</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="action3" runat="server" onserverclick="Command_Click">Do Third Action</a>
```

`Command_Click` simply bubbles up an event handler to be processed by `Dashboard.aspx`

```
public void Command_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     CommandClicked?.Invoke(sender, e);
}
```

`action1` is handled on the fly with a confirmation modal which contains a simple button that runs `onserverclick` and reloads the [default state] having deleted that item using an API call.

```
 <button type="button" class="btn" id="do-action1" runat="server" onserverclick="finish-action1">Do It</button>
```

This all works as expected.

`action2` is handled by [main page] where it clears the `PlaceHolder`'s controls and then dynamically creates and loads another UserControl which displays long form details of that object.

```
UControl2 theObject = (UControl2)Page.LoadControl("~/path/to/Control2.ascx");
TheScreen.Controls.Clear();
TheScreen.Controls.Add(theObject);
```

This all works as expected also.

`action3` button is the one that is giving me the problem and just like `action2` it is handled on [main page] where it clears the `PlaceHolder`'s controls and then dynamically creates and loads another UserControl which provide a simple form with one button on it.

```
UControl3 otherObject = (UControl3)Page.LoadControl("~/path/to/Control3.ascx");
TheScreen.Controls.Clear();
TheScreen.Controls.Add(otherObject);
```

The form is very simple, contains a `<select>` elements whose `<option>` are populated using an `asp:Repeater` based on an API call that provides the DataSource for it. It also has a simple `<input>` textbox field and lastly a submit `<button>`.

```
<select id="..." name="..." required="required">
     <option disabled selected value="">select payment account</option>
     <asp:Repeater ID="..." ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" ItemType="model.namespace">
          <ItemTemplate>
               <option value="<%#: Eval("...") %>">
                    <%#: Eval("...") + "  " + Eval("...") %>
               </option>
          </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:Repeater>
</select>
<input id="..." name="..." type="text" required="required" runat="server" />
<button id="finish-action3" class="btn" runat="server" onserverclick="do-action3">Do It</button>
```

What I don't get is why `finish-action3` is not performing the actions of the handler method `do-action3`, it simply refreshes back to the [main page] with the initial state that we started from with the initial `Control1`s being rendered and nothing else, no PostBack either.

I have searched extensively and found nothing addressing this specific scenario and what I have found, everyone keeps suggesting using `asp:Button` but that makes no difference for me in the behavior.

1. As written above, clicking `finish-action3` button which is part of `Control3` will not cause the basic HTML5 validation and does not trigger the `do-action3` handler method and simply refreshes back to the [main page] where we started.
2. If I add `do-action3` to the `onsubmit` attribute **OR** add `type=submit`, I get the validation but once it passes validation, the same behavior, nothing but load the [main page].
3. Changing the element to an `asp:Button` made absolutely no difference. The validation is triggered without anything special (like using `onsubmit` attribute or having a `type=submit` but once it is validated the same behavior, never calls `do-action3` nor does it even trigger a Page_Load/PostBack on `control3` just back to the [main page].

I suspect I am overlooking some event or is not bubbling and is getting lost in the process but I can't think what it is and where and why. Why doesn't the form that is last on the screen loaded by `Control3` "submitted" by that button click not generating a `PostBack` or running the `onserverclick` handler method and simply refreshing to the main default state page, what am I missing here?

Any help would be appreciated as I have been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out what I am missing. I never encountered this in MVC or Core and it is making me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify. Basically, what you are saying is that the following does not work because the `btnFinishAction3_Click` method of the dynamically-added `Control3` user control is not firing:

Default.aspx (main page):

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="plhPlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAction3"
    Text="Do Third Action"
    OnClick="btnAction3_Click"/>
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
protected void btnAction3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddControl3();
}

private void AddControl3()
{
    Control3 objControl3 = (Control3)Page.LoadControl("~/Control3.ascx");
    plhPlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear();
    plhPlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(objControl3);
}
```

Control3.ascx:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMessage"></asp:Label>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnFinishAction3"
    Text="Finish Action 3"
    OnClick="btnFinishAction3_Click"/>
```

Control3.ascx.cs:

```
protected void btnFinishAction3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblMessage.Text = "Finished Action 3.";
}
```

This is normal behavior. After postback the dynamically added user control does not exist and the event is "ignored". In ASP.NET Web Forms, every dynamic control must be re-added to the page after every postback. So, you need something like the following:

Default.aspx (main page):

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="plhPlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hifControl3Loaded"/>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAction3"
    Text="Do Third Action"
    OnClick="btnAction3_Click"/>
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    if (hifControl3Loaded.Value == "1")
    {
        AddControl3();
    }
}

protected void btnAction3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddControl3();
    hifControl3Loaded.Value = "1";
}

private void AddControl3()
{
    Control3 objControl3 = (Control3)Page.LoadControl("~/Control3.ascx");
    plhPlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear();
    plhPlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(objControl3);
}
```

In other words, you need to add `Control3` to the main page at every postback on `Page_Load` once the user has decided to add it by clicking the `btnAction3` button in the first place.

Comment: I appreciate the effort to answer this, but despite my best efforts, it seems either I wasn't clear enough or there is a misunderstanding. There is an `onserverclick` method that is supposed to execute code and it is not doing it, it has no need to reload the control as it is not going back to that, it is supposed to make an API call and redirect to the main page, but it is not executing the code, just "moves on". That's the issue, is it any more clear?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the `do-action3` method is part of the dynamically added control. If so and since the control is not re-generated after postback, any event handlers it "contains" are considered non-existent and thus their are not fired. It does not matter whether you need the control or not per se; you *do need* to re-load it and re-add it to the page in order for the event handler method to be found and its code be executed. At the very least, you can try and copy part of your code (the API call, etc) into my example and see if it works.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, the entire "page" that is loaded by `onserverclick="Command_Click">Do Third Action` is a "Control3" that has a form and a button on it, but the call that is made by the button is not a usual submit, so the postback is not entirely necessary for me, so long as it executes the `onserverclick` that it will "call" and that's where it is not doing it and bypassing that whole event and going to the original page. I believe I see what you are saying, that by the time it reaches that eventhandler method the "control object" is no longer available, if I understand correctly?